# Segmentation fault while using par-or tactic

Tags: z3

[This smt2 script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z4ytaujrunt3ug8/1.smt2?dl=0) encounters segmentation fault. The problem arises when par-or tactic is used. It is working without this tactics.
I am using z3 4.4.0 on a "Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux" machine.

Comment: Please add all relevant code in your question. Could you also specify your question a bit more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue! There was indeed a bug in the model translation, which is now fixed in the unstable branch (as of [this](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/858ce1158d6b8708408a954bb08dba70cf1702d2)).